# Parallelizing Convolution / Kernel based image processing in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, parallel-processing, convolution

Convolution based image processing is a common technique to perform actions such as blurring, edge detection, deblurring, and so on.  The basic premise is to generate a `kernel` which is some 2D array, usually square.

The Kernel will be convolved with the image, which boils down to sweeping it across the image and doing a sum of neighbor pixels where the `kernel` weights the neighbors.

In terms of an algorithm, for a **`Kernel`** that looks something like:

```
double[3, 3]{ 
        { 0 , -1 , 0 },
        { -1 , 4 , -1 },
        { 0 , -1 , 0 }};
```

for the code snippet below, it has the following properties:

```
filterWidth = 3
filterRadius = (filterWidth - 1) / 2; // (=1)
```

There are some variables to work with:

```
img:
    Class with members:
        ushort[] Pixels
        int Width
        int Height
```

`Pixels` is just an alias for img.Pixels.  `finalPixels` is a clone of `Pixels` and has its values modified by the filter.

Now, the loops that make this go:

```
double workPixel = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
            {
                // IMAGE rows
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
                {
                    // IMAGE columns
                    // target pixel in original (and final) image
                    int sourcePxTarget = i * img.Width + j;
                    for (int k = -filterRadius; k <= filterRadius; k++)
                    {
                        // FILTER rows
                        for (int l = -filterRadius; l <= filterRadius; l++)
                        {
                            // FILTER columns
                            int sourcePxActive = sourcePxTarget +
                                k * img.Width + l;
                            if (sourcePxActive < 0)
                            {
                                workPixel += 0;
                            }
                            else if (sourcePxActive >= Pixels.Length)
                            {
                                workPixel += 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                workPixel += Pixels[sourcePxActive] *
                                    filter.Values[k + filterRadius, l + filterRadius];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // apply filter factor and bias
                    workPixel = workPixel * filterFactor + filterBias;

                    // filter bad values
                    if (workPixel > 65535)
                        workPixel = 65535;
                    else if (workPixel < 0)
                        workPixel = 0;

                    finalPixels[sourcePxTarget] = (ushort)workPixel;
                    workPixel = 0;
                }
            }
```

This algorithm is not generalized and is for 16-bit grayscale images.  `Pixels` is a 1D array of `ushort[]` without interlacing or any other modification.  The `if` `if else` and `else` statements buried in the loops effectively replace the need to pad the image in any way, though they are an unoptimized hack.

I would like to convert at least one of these for loops to a `Parallel.For` loop, but because workPixel is not threadsafe, it does not produce a functional result.  What are the right steps to take here?

Comment: You do exactly the same operation for each pixel, so you can parallelize the two first loop (the ones going through the image). Personally, I divide the images in bands (as many bands as threads), and I give one band to each thread.

Comment: Right, the issue is that `workPixel` is being used as a local variable inside the inner two loops.  It is not threadsafe, so if you parallelize the first or second loop, you will get a corrupted output, as multiple Parallel.For loops have modified workPixel concurrently, scrambling the value.

Comment: Just move workPixel after "int sourcePxTarget = i * img.Width + j;" Then is becomes a local variable ThreadSafe

Comment: That does it, thank you!  I will leave the question open, as I am not sure this is the most optimized way to do this.

Comment: I've posted an answer, plus a detail that may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

You do exactly the same operation for each pixel, so you can parallelize the two first loops (the ones going through the image). You just need to move workPixel after `int sourcePxTarget = i * img.Width + j;` Then is becomes a thread safe local variable.

Personally, I divide the images in bands (as many bands as threads), and I give one band to each thread.

There is a faster ways to do such convolutions: use a FFT. As the FFT is performed for each row and each column, the libraries already implement parallelization.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  The filters being applied in this application are small (max size 15x15px), so the FFT method will not offer a performance benefit, I do not believe.

Comment: It depends on the library language and optimizations. For 15x15 kernels, it will give you a real improvement, but if you are talking about 15x15 images, then multi-threading will not change anything either.

Comment: The images range in size from roughly 1MP to 5MP - it depends on the camera.  This, of course, will only increase with time.  On the CPU in my machine I can perform the convolution on a 1MP image in under 0.1s, which is sufficient for now.  By the time this code becomes performance limiting as it is, we would end up wanting to port it to a GPU instead, which can do thousands of MP per second vs, say, dozens.